# MPI_Get_count returning negative value for count

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

Can MPI_Get_count() return a negative value for the count? My message sizes never exceed 1138 integers. So it should not be a problem with the message length.

```
    if(MPI_Probe(MPI_ANY_SOURCE,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status) == MPI_SUCCESS)
    {
     printf("probe flag true\n");
     MPI_Get_count(&status,MPI_DOUBLE,&recv_size);
    }
```

The value of recv_size I get is negative.

Comment: Declaration of recv_size, please?

Comment: recv_size is declared as an integer.

Comment: `MPI_UNDEFINED` is `-32766` in both Open MPI and Intel MPI.

Answer (score 1):

MPI_Get_count will return MPI_UNDEFINED (which is most likely negative) iff the message size is not a multiple of the size of the datatype given to MPI_Get_count. So maybe you are sending 5 Bytes as MPI_BYTE but you ask MPI_Get_count how many MPI_DOUBLES you received.

Comment: This is my declaration of mpi_send : MPI_Send(T,(m->ncols),MPI_DOUBLE,map(j,procs),0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

Answer (score 0):

I just realised that it was a problem with the data I was sending. The values exceeded the sizeof double. Fixed it and the code worked. Thanks for the help and sorry for buggy code!